# "Content Still Installing" for missions at War Table

Tags: technical-issues, dragon-age-inquisition

I just recently got an XBOX ONE and a physical copy of DA:I which I immediately installed and began playing.

After doing a few quests in The Hinterlands, I returned to the war table only to find that quite a few of the missions weren't allowing me access, saying "Content Still Installing" despite the fact that my XBOX was telling me that the game was 100% installed.

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced the same thing on the XBOX ONE and what they did to remedy it as I really want to progress with the storyline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. I quit the game, took the disc out and then put it back in and it the "content still installing" went away.