# Dragon Age Inquisition Content installing

Tags: technical-issues, dragon-age-inquisition

I have the content installing issue in the war room.

As suggested at ["Content Still Installing" for missions at War Table](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/content-still-installing-for-missions-at-war-table), I've tried quitting, removing the disc, and restarting the game, but to no avail. Is there a solution for this when the usual method fails?

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I play on Xbox 360 but I assume that the data is corrupted. Go into the settings of your console > system/storage > delete the files that make up the downloadable content > reinsert the disk and install the content.